# mysql query to get sum of a field less than a limit grouped by another field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table orders like:

```
order_id int ,type string ,weight double.
```

Example:

```
|        4 |  type1 |  9.729999542236328 |
|        5 |  type2 | 13.930000305175781 |
|       14 |  type4 |  9.399999618530273 |
|       17 |  type1 |  3.490000009536743 |
|       20 |  type3 |  6.349999904632568 |
|       25 |  type3 | 12.869999885559082 |
|       31 |  type4 | 1.3700000047683716 |
|       40 |  type5 | 20.079999923706055 |
|       42 |  type2 |    9.0600004196167 |
|       45 |  type2 | 15.390000343322754 |
```

I want to get rows grouped by id where the total weight is less than 500.

Example:

```
{order_ids: [1, 2, 3], total_weight: 450 }
{order_ids: [4, 5, 6], total_weight: 470 }
{order_ids: [7, 8, 9], total_weight: 400 }
```

I want to get the ids' of the orders and the total weight of them. I have 200k+ lines on the table so performance is a big focus for me. I haven't shared any query because I don't know where to start.
I am using golang with gorm and mysql 8.0.21.
I don't need to find the optimal solution it can be FIFO.

Comment: Please replace example data with one which **strictly** matches desired example output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(order_id ORDER BY order_id) order_ids, 
       SUM(weight) total_weight
FROM (SELECT test.*,
             @current_group := @current_group + (@current_weight + weight > @max_weight) group_number,
             @current_weight := weight + @current_weight * (@current_weight + weight <= @max_weight) cumulative_weight
      FROM test, (SELECT @current_weight := 0, @current_group := 0) variables
      ORDER BY order_id) subquery
GROUP BY group_number;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=26e1c0814593844b0d40338261f47c1c)

PS. Of course this query cannot find optimal "cutting stock problem" solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with tt as (
      select tt.*,
             row_number() over (order by rand()) as seqnum
      from t
     ),
     recursive cte (
      select order_id, weight, weight as running_weight, 1 as grp
      from tt
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select tt.order_id, tt.weight,
             (case when tt.weight + cte.running_weight >= 500 
                   then tt.weight else tt.weight + cte.running_weight
              end),
             (case when tt.weight + cte.running_weight >= 500
                   then grp + 1 else grp
              end)
      from cte join
           tt
           on tt.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6c2b1e0e280fb33a7a6a2f5377f7e23

Comment: I am going to test to see which one has better performance thank you!

Comment: @fbarril . . . That will be interesting.  Report back.  I would expect that the variables might be slightly better.  That said, setting variables in a `select` statement is deprecated starting in version 8.0.